# How do i mention two roles in discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === ['Muted' || 'muted'])
```

The code above is for a mute (and unmute) command. Normally servers have the `M` capital or small which affects the role in the coding. With the code above it returns an error saying `Unknown code`

Answer (score 3):

For starters, let's look at what your code is actually doing.

```
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === ['Muted' || 'muted'])
```

This code is equivalent to

```
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === ['Muted'])
```

because `"string" || "otherString"` evaluates to `"string"`. Note that this comparison will always fail, because different arrays can't be compared using the `===` operator.

```
["muted"] === ["muted"] // this is false
```

If you want to do checks against arrays you'll need to implement some iterative logic yourself or use one of the useful helpers like `Array#some` and `Array#includes`.

The correct way to do a case-insensetive comparison would probably be something like

```
const role = 
  message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name.toLowerCase() === "muted")
```

If you really only want to support `Muted` or `muted` (and not `mUtEd` for example), your method can work with a small tweak.

```
const role 
  = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => ["muted","Muted"].includes(role.name))
//                                         ^ anonymous array of acceptable values
```

Answer (score 1):

Lowercase the role name and compare it to a lowercase string

```js
const role = message.guild.roles.cache
   .find(role => role.name.toLowerCase() == 'muted');
```

If you ever do need to check a string array for possible role names use `Array#includes()`

```js
const role = message.guild.roles.cache
   .find(role => ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].includes(role.name));
```